# OrderBy with enumerable property in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object array where every object can have an array of properties, like this

```
 [
  {
    name: 'Big house',
    properties: [{name: 'Area',value: '400'}, {name: 'Year',value: '1950'}]
    },
  {
    name: 'Small house',
    properties: [{name: 'Area',value: '400'}, {name: 'Year',value: '1950'}]
    },
  {
    name: 'Green house',
    properties: [{name: 'Area',value: '40'}, {name: 'Year',value: '2008'}]
    },
  {
    name: 'Red house',
    properties: [{name: 'Area',value: '250'}, {name: 'Year',value: '1999'}]
    },
];
```

Now I'd like to order this list by one of the properties, say Area, using a filter in ng-repeat. Is that possible?

I've been play around with this in plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/GEgLxv5zJyW0ZBTtJR5S?p=preview) but cannot figure out how to do.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This will work if the area is always the first property:

```
<tr ng-repeat="house in houses | orderBy:'properties[0].value'">
```

Also make sure that the area is defined as an integer, right now they are strings. So 250 will be sorted before 40.

So remove the quotes from the numbers:

```
  {
  name: 'Area',
  value: 400
  }
  , {
  name: 'Year',
  value: '1950'
  }
```

Comment: The problem is I want to be able to sort on all properties. But I might know in which order the properties are returned, så that might help, but a solution like orderBy:'properties["Area"].value' would be preferable.